# Inclure code JavaScript in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I want do this:

```
if(substr($xxx, -1)=="yyyyy"){
     $rrr = str_replace('xxx', 'yyyyy', $uuu);
     if (property_exists($this, $yyyy)){
        echo "if(!this.value){"
            echo "  var yyyy= dijit.byId('$yyyy').get('value');";
        echo " if(yyyy){"
        echo "  var aaaaa = getDate('$this');"; 
        echo "  yyyy.constraints.min=aaaaa;";
        echo " }";
        echo "}";
      }
}
```

I have an error when I try to add my code JavaScript . 
My error is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';' in D:/www/********* on line **** (
>   echo "if(!this.value){"
>                   echo "  var yyyy= dijit.byId('$yyyy').get('value');";)

Anyone can help me ? Thanks

Comment: You're missing a semicolon in `echo "if(!this.value){";` <- HERE and `echo " if(yyyy){";` <- HERE

Comment: Oh yes !!!!!! Thaks you so much ! i'm a banana ! xD

Comment: Use php `heredoc`, check my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing several semicolons, why not use [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)? i.e.:

```
<?php
if(substr($xxx, -1)=="yyyyy"){
    $rrr = str_replace('xxx', 'yyyyy', $uuu);
    if (property_exists($this, $yyyy)){
        echo <<< EOF
        if(!this.value){
            var yyyy= dijit.byId('$yyyy').get('value');
            if(yyyy){
                var aaaaa = getDate('$this'); 
                yyyy.constraints.min=aaaaa;
                }
        }
EOF;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try !! Thanks